# Difference between FlatList and VirtualizedList

Tags: react-native

I am new in react native, and am confused about the difference between `FlatList` and `VirtualizedList`.

So,

1. **What are the differences between `FlatList` and `VirtualizedList` ?**
2. **When should I use each ?**

Comment: See the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html. You should use Flatlist by default, but only if you need more flexibility than you can use VirtualizedList.

Comment: I read the docs. but couldn't get deep differences between them.

Comment: In general, `VirtualizedList` should only really be used if you need more flexibility than `FlatList` provides, e.g. for use with **immutable data** instead of **plain arrays**

Answer (score 6):

The <**FlatList**> is a performant interface for rendering basic, flat lists.

On the other side, the <**VirtualizedList**> is a base implementation of the <**FlatList**> and <**SectionList**> components, which are also better documented. In general, <**VirtualizedList**> should only really be used if you need more flexibility than FlatList provides, e.g. for use with immutable data instead of plain arrays.

FlatList example:

```js
const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

VirtualizedList example:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <VirtualizedList
        data={DATA}
        initialNumToRender={4}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.key}
        getItemCount={getItemCount}
        getItem={getItem}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

More info:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist