# When to use virtualized list in React and React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In React there are popular libraries such as React-window and in React Native you have the built in virtualized list which both use Pure Components and render large lists when visible in the window.

One thing I can't find anywhere is when to use virtualization. Is there a general guide line of say over X amount of items, or if the items are complex always use it. On mobile I image when to use it would be different as you should consider mid-ranged mobile devices.

Comment: Use it whenever you see a performance problem. Using it on less items would not show any performance advantage. So if you backlash in performance, then you can use it or use it when dataset is above 500 or something.  I use it when I see its list is causing performance issue and can be improved.

Comment: virtualized show views in `window` only. If you have similar views which total height is greater than the window, you may consider to use a virtualized list. FYR: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views#performance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between FlatList and VirtualizedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920628/difference-between-flatlist-and-virtualizedlist)